# How to create custom hooks in codeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, hook

I'm making a PHP application in codeIgniter, and want flexibility using hooks. However, there are a limited number of hooks in codeIgniter, so I want to create my own.

How can I do this?

Comment: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/hooks.html

Answer (score 1):

You should open `system/core/Codeigniter.php` and look where the hooks are getting called and at what part in the page lifecycle.

On line **299** you have a hook getting called, then a `$class` is getting initialized, then another hook is getting called.

```
$EXT->_call_hook('pre_controller');

$CI = new $class();

$EXT->_call_hook('pre_controller_constructor');
```

So what's happening is Codeigniter will grab the list of `pre_controller` hooks and execute them before `$class` is initialized. After `$class` has been initialized and the `__constructor` does it's thing, the list of `__pre_controller_constructor` hooks will get executed.

So what is `$CI = new $class()` ?

The `$class` comes from the router, which has already been initialized at this point

So if the url is pointing to `mysite.com/category/products` then `$class=='category'` so what is really happening is this `$CI = new Category(); // application/controllers/category.php`

If a hook is called before the function `function &get_instance(){}` on line **232** then you won't be able to access the `super object` as the function has not yet been created. At that point your dealing with PHP alone and won't be able to access the framework.

The full documentation on hooks can be found here
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/hooks.html